# is there a web service client code generator on iOS?

Tags: ios

i am going to develop some features which need to invoke remote web service implemented by c#, i've already googled it get that join wsdl content seems like:

```
NSString *requestBody = @"<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/\" xmlns:tm=\"http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/\";
```

is there a tool could generate a class used to invoke specified web service like asp.net or java?

for example in c# open visual studio terminal execute this:

```
wsdl http://google.com/service/weather?wsdl
```

anyone get any idea?

it is disgusted with join mess of string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find a code-generator for translating a WSDL to multiple languages here: http://sudzc.com/