# WSDL and WEB Service

Tags: ios, web-services

I am new to web services even after watching a lot of videos and reading a large number of tutorials on WSDL I am unable to understand how to get URL for a method of web service from WSDL.  the WSDL file I am provided with is this http://cons.epackagepro.com/m/Service.svc?wsdl I want to call a login method of this web service. Can somebody explain that how to extract exact url for a web service/web service method from a WSDL file and how to pass parameters to a web service (in this particular case I want to call login). All the tutorials I watched tells that service tag of WSDL file has an address tag which tells about the url of the service but this WSDL does not contains one.

One last thing, can I call this service with soap, even soap is not used in binding. And what if I want to call it using HTTP GET / HTTP POST method, how parameters will be provided.

My main concern is how to get url of a web service / web service method from WSDL? The platform for which I want to use it is IOS.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's obviously under development as Service.svc shows the dev server page. How do you know this invalid WSDL file is being used (w/o any bindings) ?

Comment: infact I don't know it is complete or not but are you sure that this is under development. The url http://cons.epackagepro.com/m/Service.svc/login returns this method not allowed. Can you please tell me what does this means and it is the right way to call a method from web service

Comment: Please try http://cons.epackagepro.com/m/Service.svc as the root service URL, you'll see the page which is used to be displayed only  at the development environment. Adding the invalid WSDL document I'd say this service is not in use (if the application is working at all of course), do you have any official documentation for this particular service ? How did you get the link ?

Comment: this service is working well for asp.net. I am freelancing for a client he provided me this link. He wants me to make ios application for his running asp

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10145360/792677